# Upgraded to Debian 9.12, now have no network connection

Tags: networking, debian

When I upgraded my cloud server from Debian 8 to Debian 9.12, I lost all network connectivity.
I can neither ping the server nor ping anything from the server.

If I try to add a default gateway, I get `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

If I type `netstat -anr`, I get an empty list

There may be other obvious things I should try, but I am clearly not that knowledgeable.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP. mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: ens3: <BROADAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
     link/ether 00:16:3c:4e:a4:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`/ect/network/interfaces` contains:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
#The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

There are no files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*`

Comment: Please provide your `/etc/network/interfaces` file, along with any files residing in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`, and the output of the `ip a` command.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the requested information to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that during the upgrade process your network device got renamed. Change every occurrence of `enp0s3` to `ens3` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and it should get the IP address from the DHCP server.

Comment: Thank you so much! Made that change and rebooted and now everything works.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the configuration option `net.ifnames=1` which is enabled by default in Debian 9.

You can either:

- Update the interface name(s) in `/etc/network/interfaces`
- Set the `net.ifnames=0` as a kernel parameter

See https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames for more details

Comment: To clarifty, setting `net.ifnames=0` will return the host to having an **eth0** interface  which would leave OP in the same place with an interface mismatch in the config.  However this will stop the host changing interface name in the future if the kernel driver changes, so is a good solution.